# NSUrl with hyperlink inside a NSString?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl, mfmailcomposer

So pretty much what I am doing is attempting to add a NSUrl inside of a NSString to pass to a MFMailComposeController. I want the URL in the message field to have a hyperlink but if I just put a basic link inside a NSString, it won't hyperlink for me.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your link look like? Here is an explanation of what works (and what doesn't work): http://www.webword.com/867link5309.html

Comment: its a http://www. but I can't use dataDetectorTypes like I usually would!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put a square peg into a round peg (yes peg). NSString and NSUrl are both classes. NSString objects do not know how to hold an NSUrl object. They only know how to hold a string of characters.

If your application supports it, just put the URI address in the NSString. For example:

```
NSString someText = @"Please visit http://stackoverflow.com for more information.";
```

Comment: So how would I get it to recognize it then in a MFMailComposeController?

Comment: See my edited comment and also be sure to set the MFMailComposeController to use HTML, as outlined in DrChanimal's link.

Comment: HTML is enabled for me and it didn't create a hyperlink